# Angular ngRoute not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Im trying to config a basic angular app.

my main html:

```
<html ng-app="CostumerApp">
<head>
    <title> Costumers </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Costumer manager</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/costumerCtrl.js"></script>


</body>
```

app js

```
angular.module('CostumerApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/costumers', {
                controller: 'costumerCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
            });

       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });
```

costumerCtrl.js :

```
angular.module('CostumerApp')
    .controller('costumerCtrl', function ($scope){
       $scope.costumers = [];
    });
```

list html:

```
<table class='table table-hover table-hover table-bordered'>
```

routing is not working,
now its not finding "http://localhost:3000/costumers" and when i just do http://localhost:3000 its taking me to the project folder instead to my main html.

Im using node http-server and start like that http-server -p 3000 -a localhost . 
why my localhost:3000 is not showing the main page??

thank u !

Comment: Shouldn't the controller be 'costumerCtrl' instead of 'listCtrl'?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `$routProvider`, it is `$routeProvider`.

Comment: sorry thats not the issue

Comment: Try entering localhost:3000/main/#/costumers

Comment: sorry my bad , it needs to be: localhost:3000/costumers

Answer (score 1):

Since you have html5Mode setted as true in your app.js, you need to include this in your main.html:

```
<head>
   <base href="/">
...
</head>
```

So the html5Mode will work, and you can access without # in the URL.